# JavaScript execution throws "Error: OLE Automation error in eval: Unknown name or named argument." in wx.html2.WebView on MSW

Tags: javascript, windows, wxpython, wx.html2

I’m developing a cross-platform GUI app for Mac and Windows using `wx.html2.WebView`, using the latest wxPython 4.1.1. (Hint: The problem started appearing in 4.1. Earlier wxPython versions, as well as the wxPython 4.1.1 for Mac, don’t have that problem, but I’m trying to migrate to the latest wxPython for various benefits it has)

The Windows app throws an error message `Error: OLE Automation error in eval: Unknown name or named argument.` when executing some JavaScript on `WebView.RunScript()`.

I honestly don’t know where to start debugging. I can’t find out what JavaScript code caused the problem since the code isn’t displayed anywhere. I tried throwing in a confirmation dialog before each `RunScript()` call, but the execution doesn’t wait, and instead, the dialogs pile up over each other.

As the JavaScript code gets generated by the app on runtime, I did route all JavaScript code into a file and syntax-checked it externally, without errors.

The *only* result that shows up in Google search for that error message is this page: https://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/17893?cversion=2&cnum_hist=10 and the discussion hints at a custom protocol being used, which I’m not using, so it seems irrelevant.

Any ideas?

[image: JavaScript Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the reason behind, but I have solved the same error by adding an `<script></script>` element into the page contents. That is, for instance, replacing:

```
self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
self.browser.SetPage('<p>Hello World!</p>')
```

with this:

```
self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
self.browser.SetPage('<p>Hello World!</p><script></script>')
```